# difference infinite random vector and sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the difference between a sequence of random variables and an infinite random vector? For example, if $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables, which notation is used for an infinite random vector consisting of the $X_i$? $(X_i, i\in\mathbb N)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin with finite case. A $d$-dimensional random vector is simply an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued random variable, while a random sequence of length $d$ is a $d$-tuple with each component being $\mathbb{R}$-valued random variable. Thankfully, we need not distinguish two because the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes d}$ coincide.

Now, the same thing happens for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, thanks to the relation that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes \mathbb{N}}$. Therefore there is no need to distinguish sequence of random variables and countably infinite random vector.

Comment: Before accepting your answer maybe a further question: $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ belongs to the random vector and $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\otimes d}$ to the random sequence, right? So, would you say, it is a lack of notation if one mixes up the terms "sequence" and "random vector"?

Comment: So if you have $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ how do I know if it is a sequence or a random vector. Or is this really absolutely the same object?

Comment: Is $\mathcal B(\Omega^n)=\mathcal B(\Omega)^{\otimes n}$ valid for all Polish spaces $\Omega$? Or is it valid for all spaces?

Comment: @Julia, (1) Yes, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is for vectors and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes d}$ is for sequences. (2) Since $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ and $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))^{\otimes d}$ are isomorphic in the category of measurable spaces, there is no need to distinguish them. (It is much like we do not care about the explicit construction of $\mathbb{R}$, whether it be Dedekind cuts, equivalence classes of Cauchy sequence, or else.)

Comment: @Julia, (3) If $d\in\{1,2,\cdots\}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $(X_i)_{i=1}^{d}$ is a sequence of second countable topological spaces, then we still have $$\mathcal{B}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{d}X_i\right)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{d} \mathcal{B}(X_i). $$ The proof is essentially the same as in the case $X_i=\mathbb{R}$.